# How can I get around "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'foo' referenced before assignment" errors without global variables?

Tags: python, function, oop, object, global-variables

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, thing):
        self.thing = thing

def bar():
    foo = foo('test')

bar()
```

And here's what it produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filepath", line 8, in <module>
    bar()
  File "filepath", line 6, in bar
    foo = foo('test')
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'foo' referenced before assignment
```

I have a two part question regarding this.

Firstly, **how can I get around this**? After some Googling I found that adding a `global foo` before the `foo = foo('test')` line does the trick. But the general consensus seems to be that global variables are bad things to be avoided, so is there a way around this that doesn't use global variables?

And secondly, **why is this actually happening?** I understand about functions only being able to access variables created inside that function (and global variables of course). But I'm not trying to access a variable that was defined outside of the function, I'm just creating a new one. Logically speaking, why is it forbidden to create a new object inside a function (unless you declare it as global first)?

Comment: It happens because you think you're being clever by giving the local variable the same name as something in an outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the parser sees `foo = ...`, it marks `foo` as a local variable. Once that happens, your attempt to call `foo('test')` fails, because the local variable `foo` doesn't refer to *anything* yet, let alone a callable object.

You're going to have to pick a different name for the object you are creating.

Answer (score 0):

A variable in Python is always in **one** scope.

You try to assign to a local variable `foo` while reading a global variable `foo`.

When you assign to a variable that isn't declared with the global keyword, it is assumed to be a local variable. So when you write `foo = foo()` Python assumes that `foo` is local and then you get the error, that you a reading foo before you wrote to it.